# What is the best way to use commits in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I use vue and vuex daily to create my projects, sometimes when making http requests it is not necessary to create mutations to the state. I use this way:

```
actions:{
   theAction({},payload){
      // bla bla
   }
}
```

This way I get a warning, however I can perform the action. I have been able to observe to avoid this warning some people recommend to create this action inside the component, for my it is tedious since the ideal thing is to handle the logic from the state

My question is, what's the best practice for creating this kind of action?

Answer (score 1):

If you use this received data in many components you should store it in the state using mutation.
If you use the data in a certain component but you don't want to receive it directly from the component and can put this call in a separete js-module somewhere in the api folder where all such requests are placed.

**Update:**

This the example of js-module from api folder:
items.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  async getItems (options) {
    const { data: result } = await axios.post('/api/items', options)
    return result
  }
}
```

Usage:
MyComponent.vue

```
import itemsApi from '@/api/items'
...
export default {
...
data () {
  return {
    items: []
  }
},
methods: {
   async loadItems() {
      this.items = await itemsApi.getItems({})
  }
}
```

If you wish to use this API in several components you can create mixin with this loadItems function.

This is the example of an action and a mutation of the state module items.js:

```
import itemsApi from '@/api/items'

const GET_ITEMS = 'GET_ITEMS'

const state = {
  items: []
}

const actions = {
  async getItems ({ commit }, params) {
    const items = await itemsApi.getItems(params)
    commit(GET_ITEMS, items)
  },
}
const mutations = {
  [GET_ITEMS] (state, items) {
    state.items = items
  }
}
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

Usage:

MyComponent.vue

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'
...
export default {
...
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    items: state => state.items.items
  }),
},
methods: {
   ...mapActions({
     getItems: 'items/getItems',
    }),
   async loadItems() {
      await this.getItems({})
      // now you have the loaded items in this.items
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar question. Can you provide a more comprehensive answer on how this setup should work?

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe something useful to add.*

When using a framework like **NUXT** you are able to provide plugins. So in the case of API calls which are not related to store mutations but are practical in different components a plugin will be a obvious solution.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
    '@/plugins/register-api',
  ],
```

**~/plugin/register-api.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import api from '~/api';

export default function ({ store }) {
  store.$api = api;

  const ApiUtilityPlugin = {
    install() {
      Vue.prototype.$api = api;
    },
  };

  Vue.use(ApiUtilityPlugin);
}
```

**~/api/index.js**

```
import { service } from 'package'

export default function () {
  return {
    async getValue() {
      await service.getValue();
    },
  };
}
```

**Vue Component**

```
<script>
export default {
 methods: {
  callAPI() {
   this.$api.getValue();
 },
};
</script>
```

So in this way you are able to call different API's from all over your app without misusing the store.